# How do I display a count of items that are associated with category

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 tables for students and courses.  The first contains student names who are each in a course and the second contains the courses and each course has a checkbox associated with it.

My question is, how do I display the number of students that are in a each course that is checked?

**Example:**

1. There are three students names named Anna, Mia, and John
2. There are two courses: IT and Engineering
3. Anna and Mia are in IT and John in Engineering
4. If the "IT" is checked, it should display 2 students (Anna and Mia)
5. If both "IT" and "Engineering" are both checked it should display total number of students in all checked courses (3 students . . . Anna, Mia, and John)

I am new to programming, so I appreciate any help you can give me.  :D

Comment: Please include your code so far so we can help you with it.

Comment: ^^^ your code is necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order to help get the best answers to your question, it is important that it clearly states the issues that you are facing, with details and examples of the code that you've tried, where possible.  I've edited your original question to improve its readability, but please feel free to add more updates if I have accidentally altered your question or if you have more information that can help use give you a better answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.*, count(sc.student_id) as total
from students_courses sc
left join courses c on c.id = sc.course_id
group by c.id
```

Here I assume that you have 3 tables.

```
courses (id, name, status)
students(id, name, email, ...)
students_courses (id, course_id, student_id)
```